# Is my thinking about polarization signal right?

Tags: waves, polarization

I saw this mathematical formula in this paper about communication

Polarization signal is different from the temporal signal, it is the two-dimensional vector, that is, horizontal polarized component $H$ and vertical polarized component $V$

$$\text{polarization signal} 
=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon_i) & \sin(\varepsilon_i)e^{j \delta_i}\end{bmatrix}^T
=\begin{bmatrix}H_i & V_i\end{bmatrix}.$$

$\epsilon_i$ is polarized angle which denotes amplitude and $\delta_i$ is phase difference.

> \begin{align}
> \mathbf I
> & =\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon_i) & \sin(\varepsilon_i)\exp(j \delta_i)\end{bmatrix}^T
> =\begin{bmatrix}H_i & V_i\end{bmatrix}^T
> \tag 1
> \\
> \mathbf S
> & =\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon_s) & \sin(\varepsilon_s)\exp(j \delta_s)\end{bmatrix}^T
> =\begin{bmatrix}H_s & V_s\end{bmatrix}^T
> \tag 2
> \end{align}
>
> where $H_{i/s}$ and $V_{i/s}$ represent the H component and the V component of the corresponding PS. $\varepsilon_{i/s}$ ($\varepsilon_{i/s}\in[0,\pi/2]$) is the polarized angle which denotes amplitude relationship between its corresponding H component and V component. $\delta_{i/s}$ ($\delta_{i/s}\in[0,2\pi]$) describes phase difference between its

It does explain why don't we write the polarization signal as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon_i)e^{j \delta_i} & \sin(\varepsilon_i) \end{bmatrix}^T
\quad \text{or} \quad
\begin{bmatrix}\sin(\varepsilon_i)e^{j \delta_i} & \cos(\varepsilon_i) \end{bmatrix}^T
$$
So I search wiki about this, and I want to make sure that is my thinking right.

Polarization signal has horizontal polarized component, $H$, and vertical polarized component, $V$, that is, $\cos$ and $\sin$, and the wiki said  transverse wave do not exhibit polarization, so we don't need to multiply $e^{j \delta_i}$ to $\cos$.

Is my thinking right?

Comment: Note that questions of the form "Is this right?" tend to be poor fits for this site because the answer, yes or no, is too short to be a valid answer. Consider making the question more open ended so a proper answer can be written.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Where you write "It does explain", are you sure you didn't mean "It *doesn't* explain"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that we write polarization states in the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon) \\ \sin(\varepsilon)e^{i \delta}\end{pmatrix}
$$
instead of the forms
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon)e^{i \delta} \\ \sin(\varepsilon)\end{pmatrix},
\quad
\begin{pmatrix}\sin(\varepsilon) \\ \cos(\varepsilon)e^{i \delta}\end{pmatrix},
\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}\sin(\varepsilon)e^{i \delta} \\ \cos(\varepsilon)\end{pmatrix},
$$
or other possible equivalent choices, is **entirely because of convention** ─ there is no physics at all behind this.

- The choice of writing sin-then-cos as opposed to cos-then-sin is completely arbitrary; it corresponds to wanting $\varepsilon=0$ to match the $(1,0)$ vector, and nothing more. You can switch between the two conventions by defining $\varepsilon'=\frac\pi2 -\varepsilon$, and none of the physics gets changed ─ the only thing that changes is the precise details of how the angle $\varepsilon$ gets interpreted.
- The choice of putting the exponential phase $e^{i\delta}$ on the second component as opposed to the first is again completely up to convention; it corresponds to wanting the first component to be real (or, more precisely: you want one of the two components to be real, so it might as well be the first component), and you can equally well reverse that choice.

  The reason the choice doesn't matter is that, for a polarization state $\vec p = \begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon) \\ \sin(\varepsilon)e^{i \delta}\end{pmatrix}$, the real physical signal is given by
  $$
  \vec P(t) = \operatorname{Re}\left[ \vec p e^{-i\omega t} \right],
  $$
  and this means that changing $\vec p$ by multiplying it by some arbitrary complex phase $e^{i\varphi}$ has no effect on the physical signal other than a translation of the origin of the time axis, which is arbitrary to begin with. Thus, $\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon) \\ \sin(\varepsilon)e^{i \delta}\end{pmatrix}$ is equivalent to $$e^{-i\delta}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon) \\ \sin(\varepsilon)e^{i \delta}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varepsilon)e^{-i\delta} \\ \sin(\varepsilon)\end{pmatrix},$$ which has switched conventions, up to a relabelling of the variables.

Oh, and also: using $j$ for $\sqrt{-1}$ is used widely in the engineering literature, but not really in physics. (Ditto with the conventions $e^{j\omega t}$ and $e^{-i\omega t}$, from engineering and physics, respectively; thus, you can normally go back and forth between conventions by identifying $ j = -1 $.) It's not a big problem, just something to be aware of.